# Error: Config file has not been declared

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI
I am trying to build package: performance_test

It has a configuration file @ performance_test->cfg->performanceTest.cfg. package contains a simple publisher and subscriber.

Screen shot of my files is attached.Please zoom if isn't clear. Any help would be greatly appriciated.

```
Error: /home/nth/ocean_ws/src/performance_test/src/talker_node.cpp:21:41: error: ‘performance_test::performanceTestConfig’ has not been declared
   void configCallback(performance_test::performanceTestConfig &config, uint32_t level);
```

[image: image description]

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267082/error:-config-file-has-not-been-declared./) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2017-07-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-22**:
@BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi: please don't use screenshots to show something that is just text. Copy-paste the text into your question body and use the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it) to format it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, you should make sure the names defined in the `cfg/performanceTest.cfg` matches the names you used in you code.
Then you can try these.
In you CMakeLists.txt file, change line 30 to
`add_dependencies(talker ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})`. Then shift this line to before the line of target_link() command. Do the same thing for your listener.
After changing the CMakeLists.txt, it should look like this,

```
add_executable(talker src/talker_node.cpp)
add_dependencies(talker ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(listener src/talker_node.cpp)
add_dependencies(listener ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Try to compile again, it may help.

---

Originally posted by [Haibo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27575/haibo/) with karma: 91 on 2017-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0